# Amazon Cognito user is not created from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a user pool in Amazon Cognito. I try to create a new user in that user pool from an AWS Lambda function. The code runs without any error, however the user is not created in Cognito.

Here comes my node.js code of the lambda function.

```
async function createUserInCognito (email) {
  const userPoolId = 'eu-north-1_...';
  const clientId = '...';
  const cognito = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

  // Additional attributes for user registration
  const userAttributes = [
    {
      Name: 'email',
      Value: email,
    },
  ];

  const params = {
    ClientId: clientId,
    Username: email, // Use email as the username
    UserAttributes: userAttributes,
    Password: 'tempPass123';
  };


  try {
    const result = await cognito.signUp(params).promise();
    console.log('User registration successful:', result);

    // Optionally, confirm the user's email address
    await cognito.adminUpdateUserAttributes({
      UserAttributes: [
        {
          Name: 'email_verified',
          Value: 'true',
        },
      ],
      UserPoolId: userPoolId,
      Username: email,
    }).promise(); 
    console.log('Attribute updated')

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'User registered successfully',
      }),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error registering user:', error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        error: 'Error registering user',
      }),
    };
  }
  
};
```

The code runs to timeout and no user is generated. I have a VPC attached to the Lambda function. It has internet access and enable reaching RDS service.

I have an IAM role attached to the Lambda function. The IAM role has the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:AdminCreateUser",
                "cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes",
                "cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth",
                "cognito-idp:AdminRespondToAuthChallenge",
                "cognito-idp:AdminSetUserPassword"
                // Add other necessary actions here
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The CloudWatch log looks like the following

```
INFO Calling createUserInCognito...
INFO createUserInCognito
INFO AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider() called
INFO params set
Task timed out after 3.01 seconds
```

so the code time outs in line

```
    const result = await cognito.signUp(params).promise();
```

If I remove the .promise() call from the end, the timeout disappear. However, the user is not created in Cognito.

What problem shall I fix first? Is the .promise() necessary?

Any help is welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's no Lambda function in the posted code.

Comment: The function above is called from a Lambda function - export const handler = async (event) => {

Comment: Was there a reason not to use the `.promise()` method when calling adminUpdateUserAttributes? Also, have you verified this code basically works outside of Lambda?

Comment: Jarmod, I added .promise(). It did not fix the issue. I made some updates in the params. Now the code runs to a timeout.

Comment: So you're confident that outbound network access is fine yet CloudWatch Logs indicates a timeout? If your Lambda function can reach AWS API endpoints then increase the configured function timeout (from its default of 3 seconds). Also worth adding some logs to your post. What are you seeing in CloudWatch Logs?

Comment: I increased the timeout to 10 sec, the timeout remains. I can see items in clodwatch what I inserted in the code as conslole.log(). I also added an IAM policy. It has ne effect either.

Comment: Please include a sanitized version of your complete CloudWatch Logs for a failed/timed-out Lambda function invocation. It's not clear which call is timing out the function.

Comment: it looks the .promise() call after the .signUp() timeouts